# Scrapy won't crawl the url

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to make a simple scrapy program to scrape the quotes from website `http://quotes.toscrape.com/`. Output should be stored in a html file. But when I run the code, it won't out put anything. The terminal shows it crawled 0 page
[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFwRh.png)

This is the following code. Can you help me fine something is wrong thank you

```py
import scrapy

class SimpleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name ="SimpleSpider"
    
    def start_request(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
            ]
        
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
            
    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Files saved to %s' % filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's just a naming issue.
Use `start_requests` instead of `start_request`.

See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, its work for me. please follow standard scrapy spider.

```
import scrapy


class SimpleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "SimpleSpider"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    def start_requests(self):

        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Files saved to %s' % filename)
```